# Is there a way to use ShowReadOnly in the "modern" OpenFileDialog design?

Tags: .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I want to use an OpenFileDialog in .Net with the ReadOnly box shown.
But if i do this via the "ShowReadOnly" property, the OpenFileDialog is shown in the old win32 Design.
Is there a way to use this property (or something similar) with the newer Windows.Forms Design of the OpenFileDialog?
(The one where you can paste a file path, that looks like the general explorer window)

```cSharp
// Pseudocode
myDialog = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
myDialog.ShowReadOnly = true; // this leads to the win32 Design
myDialog.ShowReadOnly = false; // this leads to the Windows.Forms Design
myDialog.ShowDialog();
```